# On Factorization Lemma

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If $\sigma(X)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X,$ it is known that if $Y$ is $\sigma(X)$ measurable, then $Y=F(X)$ for some measurable $F.$ I am wondering if there are extensions of this factorization lemma into something of this form:

$$E[ G(X,Y) | Z ] = F(E[X|Z],E[Y|Z],Z)$$

i.e. we consider a measurable (or deterministic) function that depends on two other random variables $X,Y$ and when we take conditional expectation of this funciton w.r.t. some other random variable $Z,$ there exists a measurable function $F$ that gives mentioned relation.

Edit: For instance $E[\alpha X + \beta B | Z] = \alpha E[X| Z] + \beta E[Y|Z]$ so I can find $F(x,y,z) = \alpha x + \beta y$ that is constant on $z$ that satisfies this property. As mentioned by coudy below, you can use the factorization lemma, and obtain something that is constant on the first two parameters that I mentioned, but there is no guarentee that the same $F$ will work when I replace $X$ and $Y$ with $X'$ and $Y'$ for instance. So to some degree, I want to know whether there is such "global" $F$ can be found.

Edit: For instance for Brownian motion this sort of trick seems to be used in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1649.pdf Proposition $2.3.1$ (but for cylindrical functions, which doesn't seem to be that big of a deal).

Comment: For any random variable $T$, the conditional expectation
$E(T \mid Z)$ is a function of $Z$ since it is $\sigma(Z)$-measurable.
So $E(G(X,Y) \mid Z) = F(Z)$ for some function $F$. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @coudy not really. The question is that whether there are further factorizations available that also explicitly considers the inputted random variables. This is a random question that came to my mind, so its kinda open ended (I don't know if its possible or not). For linear $G$ this is trivially achievable for instance without the extra $Z$ parameter.